# How to make contents public or private based on flags

Tags: users, flags

I have two flags in my privacy profile settings to make contents public or private, I have two content types called 'videos' and 'albums' and two flags called 'keep my videos private' and 'keep my albums private'. I have provided user menu links as 'my videos' and 'my album' on user profile page. When other users see my profile they get these links (above mentioned) visible and they can view all my video & albums. Now what I want is when I flag my contents (using flags mentioned above) to be private, the menu links should be hidden on my profile page so that other users would not be able to see my profile. I have written below code in the menu custom block but not getting how to make contents(videos ,albums) private or public based on flagging.How can i do that?

global $user; $user_uid=arg(1); $flag=flag_get_flag(flag_name);

if($flag_is_flagged($user_uid)) { do stuff here......... }

Comment: If you are trying to list content based on flags You can  try using Drupal views module which will filter results based on flags..

Comment: I have created view pages to display content. I want if user flags content to be private then the view page should not be accessible by anyone. Rather I want to hide the link in the menu which redirects to the page.